# Samsung-specific webview issues

Tags: android, cordova, webview, samsung-mobile

I have a phonegap app that works seamlessly in Chromium and the native, unadultered Android Browser WebView.  Something in the Samsung-altered Android Browser breaks my app, and I can't for the life of me find a resource describing the differences of the Samsung browser.  This thread seems relevant, but the fix actually made things worse for me:

[Samsung Galaxy S4 and Phonegap Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16480197/samsung-galaxy-s4-and-phonegap-issue)

Is there any way to find out what the Samsung native browser is compatible with?

Answer (score 0):

Suggest loading some benchmark tests in Chromium and the WebView to compare features and discover what behaviors may not be supported:

- http://html5test.com/
- http://rng.io/

You may discover that the WebView doesn't implement a required feature as expected.